# why does this vimscript print more than it should?

Tags: python, vim

Here is the code:

```
function! test()
python << endpy
import vim
buf = vim.current.buffer
(row1, col1) = buf.mark('<')
(row2, col2) = buf.mark('>')
for i in range(row1, row2+1):
    print i
endpy
endfunction
```

If you do `so %` and then `ggVG`, `:call test()`, you will see it prints from 1 to 10 many times. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First custom vim functions should start with a capital letter. So it should be `function! Test()`

Second when you call a function on a range of lines it actually call that function one time for each line in the function. So if you select the 10 lines the function will be called ten times.

To fix this just add the word range after the function declaration so that vim knows that you will handle the range yourself.

```
function! Test() range
python << endpy
import vim
buf = vim.current.buffer
(row1, col1) = buf.mark('<')
(row2, col2) = buf.mark('>')
for i in range(row1, row2+1):
    print i
endpy
endfunction
```

Take a look at `:h E124`, `:h a:firstline` and `:h function-range-example`

Comment: Interesting, what if I want to let vim handle the range? Then the line number is dynamic, it's incrementing one by one. Suppose I want to use python-vim to write a function to add an "A" at the end of each selected line, and I don't want to handle range myself?